http.post method changes from POST to GET when HTTP is used rather than HTTPS
Encountering an issue where if we execute a script in an application we use in HTTPS then it will post correctly with the correct headers, Authorization etc with no problems.
Example of code below:
"use strict";

// Converts a string to an ISO 8601 formatted date and time.
// str - The string to convert.
// Returns a string containing the date and time in ISO 8601 format.
function convertDateTime(str) {
  // Convert the string to a date and time.
  var date = new Date(str);

  // Return the date and time in ISO 8601 format.
  return date.toISOString();
}

// Function to find the variable in the variables list.
function findVariable(variables, variableName) {
  for (var i = 0; i < variables.length; i++) {
    if (variables[i].name == variableName) {
      return variables[i];
    }
  }
  return '';
}

// Check if the user meets CITS conditions.
function CheckForCits(user) {
  var variables = directory.getLatestRecords(user.id);
  var ignition = findVariable(variables, "Ignition").value;
  var speed = findVariable(variables, "Speed").value;
  var blues = findVariable(variables, "Blues").value;
  log(user.name + " ==> Ignition: " + ignition + " , Speed: " + speed + " , Blues: " + blues);
  if (ignition && blues && speed > 0.5) return true;

  return false;
}

var output = [];
var i;
var tag = tags.getTagByName('c-its');

if (tag) {
  var userIDs = tag.userIDs;
  var Blues = 0;
  var ac = 0;
  var currentTime = directory.getServerTime();
  var Ignition = false;
  log(userIDs.length + " users with tag " + tag.name);

  for (i = 0; i < userIDs.length; i++) {
    var user = directory.getUserByID(userIDs[i]);

    if (CheckForCits(user)) {
      var devices = directory.getDevices(user.id);
      var speedInMph = user.trackPoint.velocity.groundSpeed * 2.23694;
      var speedInKmph = user.trackPoint.velocity.groundSpeed * 3.6;
      var vehicleStatus = speedInKmph >= 0.5 ? "Moving" : Ignition ? "Idling" : "Parked";
      output.push({
        "telmodId": user.username,
        "position": {
          "longitude": user.trackPoint.position.longitude,
          "latitude": user.trackPoint.position.latitude,
          "angle": user.trackPoint.velocity.heading,
          "speed": parseInt(speedInMph),
        },
        "time": convertDateTime(user.trackPoint.utcTimestamp), // Time is now in ISO 8601 format
        "trackings": [
          {
            "trackId": "standby.bluelight",
            "boolValue": true
          }
        ]
      });
    } else {
      log("Condition not met for " + user.name + ". So Skipping for vehicle: " + user.name + " (" + user.id + ").");
    }

    log("==========================================================================");
  }

  var citsBody = JSON.stringify(output);
  var citsEndPoint = "https://URLADDDRESSHERE/post";

  log(citsBody);


  http.POST(citsEndPoint, "application/json", "Authorization: Basic xyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxy==", citsBody);

  log("C-ITS " + http.statusCode + " " + http.statusMessage);
}

If we then try to use the same script/code with a HTTP address then the method changes from POST to GET.
 var citsBody = JSON.stringify(output);
  var citsEndPoint = "http://URLADDDRESSHERE/post";

  log(citsBody);

  http.POST(citsEndPoint, "application/json", "Authorization: Basic xyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyx==", citsBody);

Does any one have any idea's on what would cause this to occur as i'm currently scratching my head.
Appreciate any help and guidance; and thanks in advance! Brad.
Tested on HTTPS which operates correctly and posts the correct POST output with the correct body, content-length and Authorization. On HTTP it reverts to a GET method which is incorrect.
